# Laravel accessor not working on time field

Tags: laravel, accessor, mutators

I am trying to set a field when getting it from the database, and the corresponding accessor does not work. It simply does not execute.

My code is as follows:

**Migration:**

```
public function up(){
    Schema::table('users',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->time('start_working_time')->nullable();
    });
}
```

**Model:**

```
protected $fillable = [...,'start_working_time'];

protected $casts = [
    'start_working_time' => 'datetime:H:i',
];

protected $appends = ['start_working_time'];


public function getStartWorkingTimeAttribute($date){
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$date)->format('H:i');
}
```

What I've tried:

1. Set the field as non-null when creating the migration.
2. short the field name with a single underscore (start_time)
3. Do it through "$cast" instead of doing it with an accessor
4. put it in "$append"

But none of those methods work.

Any ideas please?

Comment: What's being stored in your database? If you put `dd($date)` in your `getStartWorkingTimeAttribute` function, what does it contain? The cast may have already turned it into a Carbon object for you.

Comment: The value is stored in DB with HH:mm:ss format. The function is not executing. It simply does nothing. I've tried everything: execute dd() function among others

Comment: When are you expecting it to execute? It'll only execute when needed, like when you output one of these models to JSON. (You also don't need it in `$appends`, that's only for computed columns not in the database.)

Comment: I just tried your code, it's working perfectly for me. What is the expected output, as @ceejayoz mentioned, try it with dd() and let us know the outcome.

Comment: OMG....@ceejayoz, you're right. I was debugging the code in the controller and it shows the time with format HH:mm:ss, but when I showed it in the view, it's displaying the right format. Thanks a lot to all for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `$appends` property is used to append new, computed attributes to a model's array / JSON form, not for existing columns. Since `start_working_time` is an actual column in your database, you shouldn't list it in `$appends`. Remove `start_working_time` from the `$appends` array.
2. If you're casting `start_working_time` as a datetime, Laravel is already returning this as a Carbon instance. Therefore, in your accessor, you don't need to create another Carbon instance. You can simply format it:

```
public function getStartWorkingTimeAttribute($date){
    return $date->format('H:i');
}
```